# undefined reference to `utf8_nextCharSafeBody_48' icu4c while building a library

Tags: c++, linker, makefile, icu

I have tried to build the stmd library (http://getassoc.cs.nii.ac.jp/package/stmd-1.1.5.tar.gz) on Ubuntu 12.04.2 amd64 which use the ICU library.
I have installed libicu-dev (version: 48) from Ubuntu repository and using the following configuration.

```
./configure --with-icu-config=/usr/bin/icu-config --with-defaultstemmer=SNOWBALL --enable-snowball=yes --enable-kill3number=yes
```

and then,

```
make
```

I got the following errors..

```
/bin/bash ./libtool --mode=link g++ -I. -g -O2 -Wall -Wno-parentheses -Wdeclaration-after-   statement -g -O -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED=1 '-DDEFAULT_STEMMER=SNOWBALL' '-DSTMD_MYSTEMMER_DIR="/usr/local/bin"' -g -Wall -O2 -Wall -ansi -pedantic -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long    -D_REENTRANT  -I/usr/include  '-DUSE_SNOWBALL=1' -I/usr/local/include -DKILL3NUMBER=1  -L/usr/lib   -ldl -lm   -L/usr/lib -licui18n -licuuc -licudata  -ldl -lm    -L/usr/local/lib -o stmd stmd.o stmc.o sigflg.o nio.o -L.  -L/usr/lib   -ldl -lm   -L/usr/lib -licui18n -licuuc -licudata  -ldl -lm    -L/usr/local/lib -lystem -lstemmer -lexpat -ldl 
libtool: link: g++ -I. -g -O2 -Wall -Wno-parentheses -Wdeclaration-after-statement -g -O -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED=1 -DDEFAULT_STEMMER=SNOWBALL -DSTMD_MYSTEMMER_DIR=\"/usr/local/bin\" -g -Wall -O2 -Wall -ansi -pedantic -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include -DUSE_SNOWBALL=1 -I/usr/local/include -DKILL3NUMBER=1 -o stmd stmd.o stmc.o sigflg.o nio.o  -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/home/kobkrit/stmd-1.1.5 -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -lm -lystem -lstemmer /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so -ldl
/home/kobkrit/stmd-1.1.5/libystem.a(normalizer.o): In function `utf8toutf16':
/home/kobkrit/stmd-1.1.5/normalizer.c:177: undefined reference to `utf8_nextCharSafeBody_48'
/home/kobkrit/stmd-1.1.5/normalizer.c:191: undefined reference to `u_errorName_48'
/home/kobkrit/stmd-1.1.5/libystem.a(normalizer.o): In function `utf16toutf8':
/home/kobkrit/stmd-1.1.5/normalizer.c:227: undefined reference to `u_errorName_48'
/home/kobkrit/stmd-1.1.5/normalizer.c:219: undefined reference to `utf8_appendCharSafeBody_48'
/home/kobkrit/stmd-1.1.5/normalizer.c:223: undefined reference to `utf8_appendCharSafeBody_48'
/home/kobkrit/stmd-1.1.5/libystem.a(normalizer.o): In function `normalizer_sparse_tostr':
/home/kobkrit/stmd-1.1.5/normalizer.c:125: undefined reference to `unorm_normalize_48'
/home/kobkrit/stmd-1.1.5/normalizer.c:138: undefined reference to `unorm_normalize_48'
/home/kobkrit/stmd-1.1.5/normalizer.c:140: undefined reference to `u_errorName_48'
/home/kobkrit/stmd-1.1.5/libystem.a(ngram.o): In function `nextchar':
/home/kobkrit/stmd-1.1.5/ngram.c:158: undefined reference to `utf8_nextCharSafeBody_48'
/home/kobkrit/stmd-1.1.5/ngram.c:150: undefined reference to `utf8_nextCharSafeBody_48'
/home/kobkrit/stmd-1.1.5/libystem.a(ngram.o): In function `ng_output':
/home/kobkrit/stmd-1.1.5/ngram.c:182: undefined reference to `utf8_appendCharSafeBody_48'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [stmd] Error 1
```

It seems about the problem between linker to ICU library, so I take a look on Makefile, I found

```
...
CFLAGS+=$(shell /usr/bin/icu-config --cflags)
CFLAGS+=$(shell /usr/bin/icu-config --cppflags)

LDFLAGS+=$(shell /usr/bin/icu-config --ldflags-searchpath)
LDFLAGS+=$(shell /usr/bin/icu-config --ldflags)
...
(I don't quite sure, does it relate to the problem or not?)
```

I tried build the stmd library on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS amd64 and it went fine and work perfectly. But sadly my server's hardware is not compatible with the old Ubuntu. Please help.

Comment: I have tried the older version of icu such as icu46, icu42, and icu36 but these errors have still shown up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command line:

```
g++ ... -licui18n -licuuc -licudata  -ldl -lm ... -o stmd stmd.o stmc.o ...
```

is *incorrect*: the order of object files and libraries on command line [matters](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).